# The network device driver send multiple packets to the upper layer. but, the socket in the application does not receive some packets

Tags: networking, linux-device-driver

I am making a network device driver in linux.

when received UDP packets, I make sk_buff and send upper layer using netif_rx_ni() function.
netif_rx_ni() returns NET_RX_SUCCESS.
However, the socket in the application does not receive some packets.

I tried changing the values of /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default, rmem_max, netdev_max_backlog and /proc/sys/net/unix/max_dgram_qlen and so on
but, there were no significant changes.

During the test, when I put the print line in for debugging, I saw that more packets were passed to the application layer.
Is it caused by forwarding many packets in a short period of time?
Then why is the return value of netif_rx_ni() NET_RX_SUCCESS?
If the packet is lost after netif_rx_ni() how can i solve this problem?

Comment: UDP doesn't offer any guarantees.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I'm experiencing the same right now and would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just with CAN packets instead of UDP, and found the following solution:

Previously, I used the function `netdev_alloc_skb()` to allocate memory for the skbuff. This function does not clean the memory before returning a pointer to it, so sometimes, when by chance memory at the same address was allocated multiple times in a row for different packets, remainings of the previous packets seem to have caused issues in transmission of the packets to the socket.

Replacing the function by `alloc_can_skb()`, which does do some tidying up before returning the pointer, fixed the problem for me.